# Android multicast audistreams merge - a walki talki principle

Tags: android, audio, multicast

Need an advice. My App is sort of walki talki.

An Android App starting sending the Mic voice(PCM byte array) to multicast group. Parallel the same app listening to that group in order to get the voice from other participants. Own packets are filtered by IP address. Other packets are sending to speakers of the phone.

Problem: If two or more participants broadcasting to the group, what should I do with so many PCM packets?

- Merge in one array and send to speakers?
- How big can be the byte array in terms of speaker latency?
- Other ideas, how to handle the PCM in multicast?